# Trouble generalising the concept of complementary functions from second-order ODEs to $n$-th order ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

#### Background

For a second-order, linear, homogenous ODE with constant coefficients,
$$\frac{\text d^2y}{\text dx^2}+A\frac{\text dy}{\text dx}+By=0$$
I am well familiar with the concept of the corresponding characteristic equation
$$r^2+Ar+B=0$$
whose solutions $r_1,r_2$, depending on their nature, give solutions to the ODE
$$\begin{cases}\text{two real roots},&y=Ae^{r_1x}+Be^{r_2x}\\\text{one repeated real root},&y=Ae^{rx}+Axe^{rx}\\\text{two complex roots,}&y=e^{\alpha x}(A\cos(\beta x)+iB\sin(\beta x))\end{cases}$$
where the complex roots are expressed as $\alpha\pm\beta i$.

#### What I am struggling with

Today, my professor used the following reasoning which I do not understand:
$$\text{Consider the fourth-order ODE }\\\,\\\frac{\text d^4x}{\text dt^4}-2\frac{\text d^3x}{\text dt^3}+5\frac{\text d^2x}{\text dt^2}-8\frac{\text dx}{\text dt}+4x=e^t\\ \,\\\text{then the characteristic equation is}\\\,\\r^4-2r^3+5r^2-8r+4=0\Longrightarrow(r-1)^2(r^2+4)=0$$
So far so good. I understand that the concept of a characteristic equation extends to $n$-th order DEs.
$$\text{therefore, the complementary function is}\\\,\\(At+B)e^t+C\cos{2t}+D\sin{2t}$$
**This is what I do not understand.**

#### My questions

1. How did my professor conclude that the complementary function is $(At+B)e^t+C\cos{2t}+D\sin{2t}$?
2. I was not aware that this concept extended to higher-order DEs. Higher order DEs' characteristic equations have many more possibilities than "two real roots, one repeated root, or two complex roots". How do I deal with this—is there a formal definition of how to proceed?
3. This feels a little like magic. It looks like my professor did some sort of sum of a repeated root condition and then a complex roots condition. Is some sort of linearity theorem at play?

Comment: Thank you, @Moo, it is indeed a nice write up. I don't think it answers the question however? Looks like it details the method of undetermined coefficients in general. My question is about how this concept generalises for higher order linear ODEs, and specifically, how my professor found the complementary function for a third order ODE.